# Sitecore icons corrupted on install

Tags: sitecore

I'm getting the following error in the Sitecore editor when I go to Configure > Icons and attempt to click "More Icons":

Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\temp\icons_Applications.html' is denied.

What would be the easiest way to sync the icons on the web site with the installation package, without having to start over and re-install the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that perhaps the app pool of your IIS site doesn't have rights to create temp files which is where the icons are placed after you first open them. Sitecore uses the `Website\temp\IconCache` folder to store the icons. Make sure your app pool for the IIS site has the right privileges per the installation guide, in this case it looks like write access is not fully granted.

The default IIS App Pool identity would be either Network Service or ApplicationPoolIdentity. Make sure that user has write NTFS permission for the `\Website` root folder of your instance.